# Getting an error when using java.lang.Long fields with a JsonDataSource if locale in the datasource object is not specified, in JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm facing aforementioned issue with jasper report when I'm trying with JsonDataSource.

I have my report data constructed into a JSON complying `String` and create a `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource` object using that which is then passed to the Jasper fillReport api:

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getJasperTemplatePath(), criteria.getReportParams(), jsonDataSource);
```

here I'm passing the JSON_LOCALE along with few other parameters, but somehow jasper wasn't able to compile the report and complained about fields with `java.lang.Long`

```
Error filling print... Unable to get value for field 'total_clickthrough' of class 'java.lang.Long'
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get value for field 'total_clickthrough' of class 'java.lang.Long'
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource.getFieldValue(JsonDataSource.java:234)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1330)
```

After debugging, found out that this is somehow due to the `locale` field being null in the JsonDataSource object. It doesn't seems to get it from the parameters. So I tried setting the locale directly to the datasource object as well, which works fine.

Then I ran into problems with my sub reports, where I use following expression to create json datasource for the report, based on a field of parent report.

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream($F{data}.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")))]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Here again it has the same issue with number values which I'm pretty sure due to the locale, but the thing is i'm not able to set the JsonDataSource locale since i'm using the expression inside report jrxml.

All the jasper examples I could find related to jsonDatasource are using json files directly using `net.sf.jasperreports.json.source`, so aren't quite relevant to this issue.

Is there anyway to get around this? 
Any help regarding this is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the JSON you're using as datasource?

Comment: @brunobastosg uhmm. it's pretty large I don't think its a good idea to post it here, but It is something like following:
`{ "report": { 
                    "total_clickthrough" : 1000,
                    "total_pageview": 2000,
                    "data": [ { 
                                     "date": "2015-03-02",
                                     "clickthrough": 10,
                                     ....
                                   }]
                      ...
                     }
}`
actually the JSON is well formatted and having all the fields as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

How was JsonDataSource instantiated?

I was getting the same error (using your JSON snippet) when I didn't provide a JSON select expression to the datasource.

I was doing this:

```
JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes()));
```

And changed to:

```
JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes()), "report");
```

Here's the full example for comparison (if you try it, change the paths):

Main.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String json = "{ \"report\": { \"total_clickthrough\" : 1000, \"total_pageview\": 2000, \"data\": [ { \"date\": \"2015-03-02\", \"clickthrough\": 10 }] } }";
        JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes()), "report");

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(new FileInputStream("/path/to/report.jasper"), null, dataSource);

        byte[] pdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/report.pdf");
        fos.write(pdf);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

report.jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="63a7bd83-eee8-41a6-8cbc-bc1ba1b44f1f">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="30"/>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[report]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="total_clickthrough" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[total_clickthrough]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="217" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="d03246a7-80ac-4d52-ab12-c988bf68afc1"/>
                <text><![CDATA[total_clickthrough]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="217" y="42" width="100" height="20" uuid="8d58ea82-ba52-46f1-9053-173ffcb100b1"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_clickthrough}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```